# Terminating infinite loop with piped command in scope

Tags: bash, unix

I have a very simple unix bash script I am using to execute a command every second. It has the following form:

```
while : ; do
  cat /proc/`pidof iBrowser.bin`/smaps | awk -f ./myawkscript.awk >> $DIRPATH
  sleep 1
done
```

The script runs fine, but it won't stop! If I hit ctrl-C while the script is running, the process does not stop, and I get the following error:

> cat: can't open '/proc//smaps': No such file or directory

Does anyone know how this can be avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider a trap function.  See [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) and [this](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html).

To trap ctrl-c, you'd define a handler, eg:

```
ctrl_c ()
{
    # Handler for Control + C Trap
    echo ""
    echo "Control + C Caught..."
    exit
}
```

And then state that you wish to trap it with that handler:

```
trap ctrl_c SIGINT
```

### Alternatively...

you could run the script in the background by appending &, e.g.

```
$ ./your_script.sh &
```

Which would present you with a job id in [square brackets]:

```
$ ./your_script.sh &
[1] 5183
```

(in this case 1).  When you were done, you could terminate the process with

```
$ kill %1
```

Note the percent sign indicates you are referencing a job and not a process id

Comment: Both of these approaches work (I'm in favour of the first). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -f ./myawkscript.awk /proc/`pidof iBrowser.bin`/smaps >> $DIRPATH \
  || exit 1
```

will exit the script if the `awk` invocation fails, which happens when `pidof` fails due to an erroneous path. I've taking the liberty of removing your [UUOC](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html).

Comment: Thanks, this almost worked. I can bail out of the script within a short period, but if I leave it running I cannot stop it. I no longer get the error though.

Comment: You've remove a UUOC, but added a UR (useless redirection)!  Omit the '<' and pass the file name as an argument to awk.

Comment: @William Pursell: very well, edited. But note that this redirection is not entirely useless. It guarantees that `awk` will not even be launched if the file cannot be opened by the shell. (A micro-optimization, I know.)